# Is there a distance measure between probability distributions to measure if one is a subset of the other

Tags: probability-distributions

I’ve two discrete distributions, say $p$, $q$. I am looking for a distance measure (need not be a metric, something like KL divergence is also fine) that satisfies the following:

1. If support of $q$ is a subset of support of $p$, then the distance should be zero.
2. If support of $q$ contains values not in support of $p$, then the distance should indicate how far should $q$ be moved so that it’s support becomes a subset of support of $p$.

Comment: And what if $q$ cannot be moved so that its support becomes a subset? Can you just take $\sup_{x\in Q}\textrm{dist}(x,P)$, where $P,Q$ are the respective supports, which is "half" of the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Definition) between $P$ and $Q$? It will give you the largest distance from points in $Q$ to $P$, and will be $0$ if $Q$ is a subset.

Comment: Thanks! I think this should be fine.